# How to fix unsafe attempt error and show the caption?

Tags: html, html5-video, caption, webvtt

This is the HTML code
`<video controls width="1000"> <source src="Video/Conan.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <track kind="captions" src="captions/cap.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"> </video>`

This is the VTT File
WEBVTT

1
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:05.000
This is the caption 1

2
00:00:05.000 --> 00:00:10.000
This is the caption 2

This is the Error showed by console
Unsafe attempt to load URL  file:///C:/Users/USER/Documents/Front%20End/HTML5/AUDIO%20&%20VIDEO/captions/cap.vtt from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/USER/Documents/Front%20End/HTML5/AUDIO%20&%20VIDEO/AuVi.html. 'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins.

I've tried my best, but I think I can't solve this alone. If you are a kind-hearted one, please help me, I'm newbie.

I want to show the caption, but when I click the caption button, it always disappeared itself.

Comment: In Which browser do you get this error?

Comment: Some web APIs cannot be tested from hard drive. Your HTML file and VTT must be on a web server for the code to work. You can install [XAMPP for Windows](https://www.apachefriends.org/fr/download.html) for when you want to use a local Windows folder as if it was an online web space. Basically it gives you access to a `localhost` address for testing (if you don't already have one).